# Django-mediagenerator can't find Sass

Tags: django, rubygems, sass, django-mediagenerator

I'm trying to setup django-mediagenerator with Sass, but whenever it tries to compile the `.scss` files, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Failed to execute Sass. Please make sure that you have
>   installed Sass (http://sass-lang.com) and Compass
>   (http://compass-style.org). Error was: [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory

I've installed both the `sass` and `compass` gems...

```
gem install sass
gem install compass
```

...And I can verify that they are both installed...

```
sass --version
compass --version
```

What exactly have I missed? Does `sass` need to be installed in a specific location? Do I need to set up some sort of virtual environment like I have with python?

**Edit:**
If I run `which sass` I get the following:

```
/Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/sass
```

Comment: I've included the results of `which sass` in the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`django-mediagenerator` assumes that the `sass` executable is in the `PATH` environment variable.  In this case, your web server is *not* running with the same `PATH` as your normal user environment. You should either add `/Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/` to the PATH where the web server is launched, or install `sass` and `compass` in a location which is already included.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem :S
Thanks :)

Comment: It is common etiquette to upvote an answer you found helpful, not just accept it. (Current upvote is mine.)